# Previously selected tab no longer remembered on ....stackexchange.com/questions page

Tags: support, status-completed, question-lists, tabs

When visiting the questions page, e.g. here on meta https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions the previously visited tab is no longer selected by default.

Previously it would automatically show the `active` tab if this had been the last tab I used in my previous visit. Now it seems that no tab is selected by default.

[image]

I experience the problem both with firefox and opera

Comment: I always thought that the root domain was Active and the "questions" link was Newest? It's supposed to remember what you were on?

Comment: @TheWanderer The root domain is missing the preview of the post body (the first few lines) and the user icon. These things are only visible in the questions->active tab

Comment: This regression is probably my fault.  I'm checking on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed.

After refactoring some code, I accidentally ended up with code that functioned like this:

```
if (!Enum.TryParse(sort, true, out ListViewData.Sorts lSort))
{
    actualSort = GetQuestionSortOrder(lSort, CurrentUser);
}
```

This code executed used the extracted value of `lSort` even though parsing failed.  Instead of passing in `null` which would have fetched the saved value, I was passing `default(ListViewData.Sorts)` which is of no use to anybody.

Incidentally, I didn't make the same mistake in tagged question lists, so /questions/tagged/support is working like it should.  There's something to be said for modern functions that return `Nullable<T>` rather than using out parameters<sup>[1]</sup>.

---

<sup>[1] I'm old enough to remember when `TryFoo(out)` was the modern replacement for `try { Foo() }`</sup>